# Magento observer modify currenlty loaded collection

Tags: php, magento

I have made a simple observer that triggers on "catalog_block_product_list_collection"

```
<config>
<global>
<modules>
    <Bz_Customfilter>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Bz_Customfilter>
</modules>
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <Bz_Customfilter_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Bz_Customfilter_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>Customfiltermethod</method>
                </Bz_Customfilter_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
    </events>
</global>
```

My wish is once user clicks on category, magento would load all products (not just those that belong to currently selected category) and filter them by certain attribute. No matter how I try to change the collection, I always get only products from selected category. Can anyone help me with this?

My Observer.php:

```
class Bz_Customfilter_Model_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function Customfiltermethod($observer)
    {

        if(Mage::registry('current_category') &&(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()=='103') ):
            $collection=$observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('filter', '1');
        endif;
        return $this;

    }
}
```

I already tried loading products via `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` and modifying collection with: `$observer->getEvent()->setCollection()` but with no luck. Collection is always limited to selected category.

Comment: The [system.reactive] tag is the .NET namespace for Microsoft's Reactive Extensions. I don't think that's what you wanted.